# How to create a template with parameters in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 3 List views. They are very similar. The only difference is that their ItemsSource binds to different variables. Is there a way to create a template list view with unknown ItemsSource, and I can pass a parameter to fill that ItemsSource?

My code is something like this:

```
<ListView Name="View1" ItemsSource={"Binding Student1"}>
    <TextBlock Text={"Binding Name"}/>
</ListView>

<ListView Name="View2" ItemsSource={"Binding Student2"}>
    <TextBlock Text={"Binding Name"}/>
</ListView>

<ListView Name="View3" ItemsSource={"Binding Student3"}>
    <TextBlock Text={"Binding Name"}/>
</ListView>
```

Edit:
I might have expressed my question in a wrong way. I would like to have a separate user control view called "StudentView":

```
<ListView ItemsSource=Parameter1>
    <TextBlock Text={"Binding Name"}/>
</ListView>
```

So that in my main window, I can do something like this:

```
<local:StudentView Parameter1={"Binding Student1"}/>
```

Comment: You do not need this at all. Simply create a DataTemplate resource with `DataType="{x:Type local:YourStudentClass}"` that contains the TextBlock. It would automatically be applied to all item container of ListBoxes that have their ItemsSource property bound to a collection of the YourSudentClass type.

Comment: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: And use ListBox, not ListView. You would use ListView only when you set its View property.

Answer (score -2):

You are on the right track with thinking about templating

What you are looking for is something called a ControlTemplate.

Your **ControlTemplate** would then target the ListView control and use the key word **TemplateBinding** to pass through the ItemsSource binding from your ListView

You would look to add this as a window resource as shown below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate" TargetType="ListView">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This would enable you to use this template on your **ListView** controls as shown below

```
<ListView Template="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"/>
<ListView Template="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList1}"/>
<ListView Template="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList2}"/>
```

Hope this gives you what you were looking for

Comment: A ListView in the ControlTemplate of a ListView makes no sense at all. You would have two ListViews instead of one.